# ¿Por qué sale este error al imprimir los datos ordenados?

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un programa que le pueda ingresar varios números y al final me arroje los números en orden pero por alguna razón me da error, alguien me puede ayudar explicándome por que? les comparto el código. De ante mano muchas gracias...

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numero[] = new int [5];
                
                
                Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        
                
                for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    
                    System.out.println("Ingrese numero " + i);
                    //numero[i] = Integer.parseInt(leer.nextLine());
                    numero[i] = leer.nextInt();
                    
                }
                
                Arrays.sort(numero);
                
                for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                
                System.out.println("El orden de numeros es " + numero[i]);
                
                }
                
               
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El único error que tienes es que en el segundo `for` tienes un 6 en lugar de un 5.

Cuando uses un `for` para recorrer un arreglo te recomiendo no colocar directamente la longitud del arreglo sino usar la propiedad `length` del mismo, de esa forma si el arreglo cambia de tamaño no se debe modificar el `for` .

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numero = new int[5];
    
    
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    
        for (var i = 0; i < numero.length; i++) {
    
            System.out.println("Ingrese numero " + i);
            //numero[i] = Integer.parseInt(leer.nextLine());
            numero[i] = leer.nextInt();
    
        }
    
        Arrays.sort(numero);
    
        for (var i = 0; i < numero.length; i++) {
    
            System.out.println("El orden de numeros es " + numero[i]);
    
        }
    
    
    }
```

Comment: gracias, no puedo creer que era eso... estuve horas analizándolo y no me di cuenta...

Answer (score 1):

En primera a mi me aparece que es de Java y no estoy seguro de porque usas "var" en vez de "int", la segunda es que metes 5 números y quieres imprimir 6 en el segundo ciclo for.
Ya por ultimo lo único que te puedo recomendar es mejorar la identacion de tu código, pero ya con los cambios quedaría algo así:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numero[] = new int [5];
                
                
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        
                
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    
            System.out.println("Ingrese numero " + i);
            //numero[i] = Integer.parseInt(leer.nextLine());
            numero[i] = leer.nextInt();
                    
        }
                
        Arrays.sort(numero);
                
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                
            System.out.println("El orden de numeros es " + numero[i]);
              
        }
               
               
    }
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!

Comment: El [var](https://developer.oracle.com/java/jdk-10-local-variable-type-inference.html) solo le indica al compilador que infiera el tipo. Es útil usarlo cuando el tipo es extenso (como por ejemplo, `List<Integer>)`..

Comment: Muchas gracias MrDave1999, realmente es mi error por no mantenerme informado sobre lo de la variable var.

Comment: @EtsuHen No hay de que, de los errores se aprende :)

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar la forma de declarar variables en el for es mediante int y no con var. Por otro lado para recorrer el arreglo debes usar la propiedad length.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int numero[] = new int [5];

    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < numero.length; i++) {

        System.out.println("Ingrese numero " + i);
        //numero[i] = Integer.parseInt(leer.nextLine());
        numero[i] = leer.nextInt();
    }

    Arrays.sort(numero);

    for (int i = 0; i < numero.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("El orden de numeros es " + numero[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus consejos, son de mucha ayuda para mi que estoy empezando!!

Comment: Te recomiendo la web de https://www.hackerrank.com/ donde puedes encontrar desafíos básicos  y avanzados en Java que te pueden ayudar mejorar. De igual manera puedes encontrar en otros lenguajes.

Comment: *En primer lugar la forma de declarar variables en el for es mediante int y no con var...* A partir de Java 10, se introdujo la [inferencia de tipo de variable local](https://developer.oracle.com/java/jdk-10-local-variable-type-inference.html). Así que ambas formas son correctas. No es común usar el `var` en los bucles for, pero de que se puede, se puede.

Answer (score 0):

El problema radica en esta línea de código:

```java
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
```

El array `numero` solo admite índices que estén en el rango de `0` a `4` y en este caso, estás desbordando el array, por esa razón la *JVM* lanza esa excepción.

La solución más simple es usar el bucle [foreach](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach#Ejemplo_en_Java) de Java:

```java
for(int n : numero)
    System.out.println(n);
```

De este modo, evitas:

- Preocuparte en crear una condición de salida.
- Un posible desbordamiento (pasarse de los límites del array).